# Как в плагине woocommerce добавить несколько фотографий на страницу категорий?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

День добрый! Подскажите, знающие люди!

Использую wordpress - wocommerce. Есть страница категорий, в которой представлены карточки товаров. Как сделать, чтобы отображалась не одна картинка товара, а, например, 5? И со слайдером. В самой карточке товара отображаются, естественно, все фотки товара.

Наглядный пример - сайт авто.ру (https://auto.ru/moskva/cars/citroen/berlingo/all/)

Подгружаются несколько картинок, есть удобный слайдер, при наведении сам переключается.

Есть ли готовое решение (плагин)? Или может с кодом подскажете?

Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Открываете страницу с категориями, смотрите template, открываете файл template, смотрите, как там выводятся карточки товаров, далее модифицируете.

Comment: @SeVlad [Вот такой template](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_template/).

Comment: Не сразу понял что ты хочешь. Там работы - в 2х словах не описать. Вкратце -  надо в **теме** в шаблоне WC *archive-product.php* добавить слайдер. В пом. https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-theme-developer-handbook/

Answer (score 0):

нужно удалить хук вывода изображения

```
 remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10);
```

поставить свою функцию и кастомизировать вывод под свою задачу

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'custom_woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10);

fucntion custom_woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail() {

     global $product;

     $post_thumbnail_id = $product->get_image_id(); 
 
     $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_image_ids(); 

     foreach ( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) {
     ?>
         <a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id ); ?>" data-fancybox="product-gallery"><img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id ); ?>" alt=""></a></div>
    <?php } 

}
```